# How do i show two text field actionListener in my showMessageDialog? Halp

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have two textFields with ActionListeners, so that I notice when the user presses enter after editing textField1 and 2. So that I can then display a message dialog with both textField 1 and 2.

But i do not know how to display both fields, it only it shows textField2 twice here? What could be causing that?

```
public JTextField textField1;
public JTextField textField2;

public TextFieldFrame(){
    textField1 = new JTextField("textField 1",30);
    textField1.setEditable(true);
    textField1.setBounds(100, 340, 300, 25);
    add(textField1);

    textField2 = new JTextField("textField 2",30);
    textField2.setEditable(true);
    textField2.setBounds(100, 370, 300, 25);
    add(textField2);

    TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();

    textField1.addActionListener(handler);
    textField2.addActionListener(handler);

    setSize(450, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
private class TextFieldHandler implements ActionListener{        
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){            
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextFieldFrame.this, String.format("testing%n1.%s%n2.%s", event.getActionCommand(), event.getActionCommand()));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! appreciate very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextFieldFrame.this, 
    String.format("testing%n1.%s%n2.%s", event.getActionCommand(), event.getActionCommand()));
```

Your text fields share the same listener so you can't use the event.getActionCommand() method twice. You will just get the same value.

I think you want something like:

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TextFieldFrame.this, 
    String.format("testing%n1.%s%n2.%s", textField1.getText(), textField2.getText()));
```

Also don't use setBounds()

```
textField2.setBounds(100, 370, 300, 25);
```

The layout manager will determine the size/location of the components based on the rules of the layout manager.

Comment: Thank you! by layout manager do you mean this ?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html